# Function that searches object array for string and returns corresponding value

Tags: c++

I need to make a function that takes an inputted date and searches through a data set of high/low temperatures for a matching date which will then return the corresponding lowest temperature for that date. The format of the date being entered matches the format in the array so that is not the issue. Currently, the function returns 0 every time. If I had to guess, I think there is something wrong with the if statement or my getDate function.

```
double findLow(const char* date, const Weather *data, int dataSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        // If date matches, return lowest temp
        if (date == data[i].getDate()) {
            return data[i].getLow();
        }   
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

Here are my other functions:

```
const char* Weather::getDate() const {
    return &date[0];
}

double Weather::getLow() const {
    return lowTemp;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot compare `const char*` like strings using `==`. That is done using `strcmp` (though it raises the question why you aren't using `std::string` instead)

Comment: Looks like you're checking pointer equality

Answer (score 0):

`date == data[i].getDate()`

You can't compare pointers that way. Better use std::string if you have to use an array anyway (most date representations should use a dedicated class) .

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::string` instead instead of `const char*`, else you compare only pointer and not string content.

```
class Weather
{
// ...
private:
    std::string date;
public:
    const std::string& getDate() const { return date; }
};
```